# integrate mailchimp on checkbox in my php form

Tags: php, checkbox, mailchimp

I just want to integrate a mailchimp code to my php form which sends now a email but I have a checkbox which a user can check or uncheck if he wants to have news and updates

```
    <div class="checkbox">
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="emailUpdates" name="emailUpdates" value="Yes">    
          Please keep me informed of product updates and news
       </label>
    </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php

                            // SUBSCRIBE TO MAILING LIST OPTION - ADD TO MAILCHIMP USING API
                            if ($_POST['emailUpdates'] == 'Yes')
                            {
                                // Include Mailchimp API class
                                require_once('MCAPI.class.php');

                                // Your API Key: http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
                                $api = new MCAPI('feaf699f7a15c1ca27f6903152d4a3f1-us3');

                                // Your List Unique ID: http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/ (Click "settings")
                                $list_id = "69010111da";

                                // Variables in your form that match up to variables on your subscriber
                                // list. You might have only a single 'name' field, no fields at all, or more
                                // fields that you want to sync up.
                                $merge_vars = array(
                                    'FNAME' => $_POST['first_name'],
                                    'LNAME' => $_POST['last_name']
                                );

                                // SUBSCRIBE TO LIST
                                if ( $api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_POST['email'], $merge_vars) === true ){
                                    $mailchimp_result = 'Success! Check your email to confirm sign up.';
                                } else {
                                    $mailchimp_result = 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
                                }
                            }

                            ?>
```

On my localhost it says

> Notice: Undefined index: emailUpdates in C:\xampp\htdocs\kinectapi\contact.php on line 98

What is wrong with my code? Any helps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

when your form `submit name="emailUpdates"` is not checked so its return this type of array `Undefined index: emailUpdates`, means array key not cantain `emailUpdates`

eg. `$_POST['emailUpdates']`